# How to update the result with MySQL or Go in special conditions?

Tags: mysql, go

I would like to update the result with MySQL or Go in special conditions:

Original data:

```
id    parent_id  grade_id 
test    admin   
test1   test    
test2   test    
test3   test1   
test4   test
```

need to update a column of `grade_id`:

```
id    parent_id    grade_id 
test    admin   
test1   test    admin
test2   test    admin
test3   test1   test
test4   test    admin
```

According to the data, if `test`'s parent id is not null (parent id is admin), then the next `test1`'s grade id is `admin`, the rest can be done in the same manner.

Comment: I don't see an actual question. Can you update your question with the code you're trying, and explain exactly how it's not working as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking for a way to update a given table, setting the `grade_id` field to be the `parent_id` of whatever record is referenced using its `parent_id` (ie `test1` has `test` as `parent_id`, which in turn has `admin` as `parent_id`, hence the `grade_id` should be `admin`).

This can be done using a pretty simple query like this:

```
UPDATE foo AS f LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ID, parent_id FROM foo
) AS j ON f.parent_id = j.ID
SET f.grade_id = j.parent_id;
```

A simple example of this query to play around with [can be found here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sVn99HD13p4JbpzyJkPDTC/0)